# Spring context without required files

Tags: java, spring

When starting Spring context I have a bean that requires configuration files:

```
<bean id="ConfBean" class="com.FailSafeConfiguration">
    <property name="loeConf" value="${gi-alert-loeconf}"/>
    <property name="cdlConf" value="${gi-alert-cdlconf}"/>
    <property name="failSafeBean" ref="failSafeBean"/>
</bean>
```

If the files are missing the whole Java application doesn't start. Is there a way for this not to happen? Even if the properties don't have anything in them?

Comment: Added possible duplicate above that uses `@Value`, but the way the property is resolved is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SpEL to default these to null:

```
<property name="loeConf" value="${gi-alert-loeconf:#{null}}"/>
```

Essentially anything after the `:` will be used as a default, so put whatever type-specific value you want in there. `${gi-alert-loeconf:true}` would work for `boolean`, `${gi-alert-loeconf:5}` would work for `int`, etc.